# How can I return the collection of contained objects from a class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I Have a class Variable and another class Variables.
Variables class is used to maintain and generate the list of objects of the type Variable.

Everything is working ok and i am happy about it. But there is one thing i dont know how to get it done.

i want to use the Variables in foreach loop like this..

```
Variables oVariables;
foreach(Variable element in oVariables)
```

But i am not able to do this by just using the object of the class Variables in this example that is oVariable. i have to write some function that will return the Collection.
So is there any way i can avoid writing an extra function and get Collection from that.

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks
Here is the code of Variables Class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace APVariable
{
    public class Variables
    {
        private Collection mCol;
        public Variable Add(string Name, object Value, string skey = "")
        {
            Variable objNewMember = new Variable();
            objNewMember.Name = Name;
            objNewMember.Value = Value;

            if (skey.Length == 0)
            {
                mCol.Add(objNewMember);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Information.Err().Clear();
                    mCol.Add(objNewMember, skey);
                    if (Information.Err().Number != 0)
                    {
                        Information.Err().Clear();
                        mCol.Add(objNewMember);
                    }
                }
                catch { Information.Err(); }
                {

                }
            }
            return objNewMember;
            objNewMember = null;
        }
        public int count
        {
            get
            {
                return mCol.Count;
            }
        }
        //public void Remove(int vntIndexKey)
        //{
        //    //this can be the int or the string.
        //    //passes the index or the key of the collection to be removed.

        //    mCol.Remove(vntIndexKey);
        //}
        public void Remove(dynamic vntIndexKey)
        {
            //this can be the int or the string.
            //passes the index or the key of the collection to be removed.

            mCol.Remove(vntIndexKey);
        }
        public dynamic newEnum
        {
            get
            {
                return mCol.GetEnumerator();
            }

        }

        public Variable this[object vIndex]
        {
            get
            {
                Variable result = null;
                try
                {
                    result = (Variable)mCol[vIndex];

                }
                catch
                {
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        //public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        //{
        //    //this property allows you to enumerate
        //    //this collection with the For...Each syntax
        //    return mCol.GetEnumerator();
        //}
        public Variables()
        {
            mCol = new Collection();
        }
         ~Variables()
        {
            mCol = null;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement the [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.  This will allow to be able to use the foreach on your class.  You should also use [Colection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx).

It looks like you've started, you're almost there.

```
namespace APVariable
{
    public class Variables : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
    {
        private Collection<Variable> mCol;
        public Variable Add(string Name, object Value, string skey = "")
        {
            Variable objNewMember = new Variable();
            objNewMember.Name = Name;
            objNewMember.Value = Value;

            if (skey.Length == 0)
            {
                mCol.Add(objNewMember);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Information.Err().Clear();
                    mCol.Add(objNewMember, skey);
                    if (Information.Err().Number != 0)
                    {
                        Information.Err().Clear();
                        mCol.Add(objNewMember);
                    }
                }
                catch { Information.Err(); }
                {

                }
            }
            return objNewMember;
            objNewMember = null;
        }
        public int count
        {
            get
            {
                return mCol.Count;
            }
        }
        //public void Remove(int vntIndexKey)
        //{
        //    //this can be the int or the string.
        //    //passes the index or the key of the collection to be removed.

        //    mCol.Remove(vntIndexKey);
        //}
        public void Remove(dynamic vntIndexKey)
        {
            //this can be the int or the string.
            //passes the index or the key of the collection to be removed.

            mCol.Remove(vntIndexKey);
        }
        public dynamic newEnum
        {
            get
            {
                return mCol.GetEnumerator();
            }

        }

        public Variable this[object vIndex]
        {
            get
            {
                Variable result = null;
                try
                {
                    result = (Variable)mCol[vIndex];

                }
                catch
                {
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            //this property allows you to enumerate
            //this collection with the For...Each syntax
            return mCol.GetEnumerator();
        }
        public Variables()
        {
            mCol = new Collection<Variable>();
        }
         ~Variables()
        {
            mCol = null;

        }

    }
}
</code>
</pre>
```

I'd recommend subclassing Collection or List or implementing IList or ICollection

Comment: Thank You Dan. That worked. I implemented the IEnumerable and GetEnumerator and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason behind implementing ICollection... i didnt get that?

Comment: Sorry I mean `Collection<T>` this way your backing store is strongly typed and you won't need to cast type `object` to type `Variable` when iterating.  @RaheelAhmad